# Laravel 5.2 form validation redirection issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am having some issues with the redirect when the form validation fails.
The code that I am using is the following:

```
// -> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

 public function subscribe(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|unique:subscriber|email',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('main')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    $email = $request->input('email');
    $randomId = $this->generateRandomUserId();
    $subscriberSource = $request->input('utm_source');

   // ... Save user
}
```

And this is my form:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
                            {!! csrf_field() !!}

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Email</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"
                                           value="{{ $email or old('email') }}">

                                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                            <ul>
                                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        <i class="fa fa-btn fa-refresh"></i>Subscribe now
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

The users should put their email in the email field and then get validated by the above piece of code. The issue is that the user is never redirected back to the main page

Comment: try to use `redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();`

Comment: I only see a redirect when the validator fails? so if the form validates it has no where to go?

Comment: @StefanoGroenland That is correct. I was testing the cases that validation fails, entering invalid data.

Comment: ah okay did you fixed it already or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|unique:subscriber|email',
]);
```

Instead of creating a new validator istance, so Laravel will automatically redirect back with all errors and all inputs to the previous page if validation fails.